# Dashboard chart console error while hovering on series

Tags: jquery, devexpress, devextreme

I am using one Devexpress dashboard chart where i am showing a chart with month wise series. When i hover on series getting this error:

Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "M 0 0 L NaN 0 L NaN NaN …".

Below is screenshot for the same:

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPksz.png)

Need help to solve this issue.

Comment: Seems issue with fetching values, from where ever you are getting

Comment: No Pankaj, When Dashboard chart is loading that time i did not find any console error, After loading when i hover mouse getting this console error.

Comment: Have you checked values when you get response to generate chart?

Comment: No pankaj this i did not checked it but value is loading fine there.

Comment: @Pankaj I checked this and got to know that value is loading fine. Issue is only when i hover in chart getting this error.

Comment: @V.Prasad please paste your code

Comment: @VictorHugoTerceros, I found one error in my code which was multidimensional array variable used while loading data due to that this issue was happening. I used there single dimension array and now this issue does not exist.

Comment: @V.Prasad good please paste your answer and mark as correct so you help someone else

Comment: @VictorHugoTerceros, Currently i don't have not earned that much reputation to add an answer. So i can't do it.

Comment: @V.Prasad, edit your question and put your answer there, or you can answer this question later so it does not remain unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have follow this [Link](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues/725) and after did not get the error again.